# Trouble Dynamically Highlighting Background - removeClass fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, background, highlight

I've got a handful of panels on my page.
I've also got a menu which should highlight it's respective panel dynamically.

It's currently working where a hard-coded button is highlighting a single, defined panel, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

I want it so the panel that gets highlighted is the the one that was chosen from the menu. It also **MUST** fade back to the original background.

I tried jqueryUI's `fadeOut`, `removeClass` and many other methods all unsuccessfully.

Things to keep in mind:

1. The panels start with a background (css) gradient.
2. I'd like to bring attention to a particular panel (highlight it)
   using the menu select. I'd like to achieve this by either:

   a) Applying a class which replaces the background with a new colored gradient (css)

   b) Using jqueryUI's built-in `effect(highlight)` function. But I don't think this will work well returning to the original background gradient.
3. The highlight should happen immediately on menu item select, then
       slowly ***fade out*** over 3-5 seconds - returning to the ORIGINAL
       background gradient.

It seems like I've got a decent start, but I'm unable to make this work the way I'm hoping for.

Any help is appreciated.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tedgrafx/FKtLJ/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Highlight Panel</a>

<ul>
    <li>Title
        <ul>
            <li onclick=" FocusPanel('panelOne')">One</li>
            <li onclick=" FocusPanel('panelTwo')">Two</li>
            <li onclick=" FocusPanel('panelThree')">Three</li>
            <li onclick=" FocusPanel('panelFour')">Four</li>
            <li onclick=" FocusPanel('panelFive')">Five</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div id="panelOne" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">One</h3>
        <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="panelTwo" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Two</h3>
        <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="panelThree" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Three</h3>
        <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="panelFour" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Four</h3>
        <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="panelFive" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Five</h3>
        <p>
        Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function FocusPanel(panelName) {
    // var panel = $( "#" + panelName );
    // $( panel ).effect( "highlight", 3000 );

    function runEffect() {
      // run the effect
      $( "#panelFour" ).effect( "highlight", 3000 );
      // $( panel ).addClass( "highlightPanel" );
    };

    // set effect from hard-coded button
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
      return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container
{ width: 100%; }

.ui-widget-content
{ background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); float:left; width:40%; height: auto; margin:0 10px 10px 0; padding: 0.4em; }

.ui-widget-header
{ margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }

.highlightPanel
{background:#ffff00;}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the "Highlight Panel" button or just have the panel become highlighted when the corresponding list item is clicked?

Comment: +1 for a well crafted question with fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I am getting you right.

Are you looking for something like this (simplifyied):

```
var highlightAssociatedPanel=function(){
    var lastActive=$(".active");
    return function(e){
        if(lastActive) $(lastActive).removeClass("active");
        lastActive=$("#"+$(e.target).data("panel")).addClass("active");
    }
}();

$("ul").on("click","li", highlightAssociatedPanel);
```

Play with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tsfer/)
Instead of adding a simple highlighting you could choose for the highlighteffect whatever CSS you want.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-highlight="panelOne">One</li>
    <li data-highlight="panelTwo">Two</li>
    <li data-highlight="panelThree">Three</li>
    <li data-highlight="panelFour">Four</li>
    <li data-highlight="panelFive">Five</li>
</ul>

<div id="panelOne" class="panel ...">
    ...
</div>

<div id="panelTwo" class="panel ...">
    ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-highlight]').on('click', function() {

    // Remove highlight class from all the panels
    $('.panel').removeClass('highlightPanel');

    // Get the panel that should be highlighted now
    $thisPanel = $('#'+$(this).data('highlight'));

    // Add highlighted class to clicked panel
    $thisPanel.addClass("highlightPanel");

    // Quick & Dirty: Remove that class after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        $thisPanel.removeClass("highlightPanel");
    },3000);
});
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FKtLJ/9/

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me is you you just need a callback after the highlight is finished animating. To do that use the following:

$(selector).animate({
         property : value
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>Title
    <ul id="menu">
        <li data-panelid="panelOne">One</li>
        <li data-panelid="panelTwo">Two</li>
        <li data-panelid="panelThree">Three</li>
        <li data-panelid="panelFour">Four</li>
        <li data-panelid="panelFive">Five</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div id="panelOne" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">One</h3>
    <p>
    Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="panelTwo" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Two</h3>
    <p>
    Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="panelThree" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Three</h3>
    <p>
    Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="panelFour" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Four</h3>
    <p>
    Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
<div id="panelFive" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Five</h3>
    <p>
    Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**
    .container
    { width: 100%; }

```
.ui-widget-content
{ background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); float:left; width:40%; height: auto; margin:0 10px 10px 0; padding: 0.4em; }

.ui-widget-header
{ margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }

.highlightPanel
{background:#ffff00;}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li').click(function(){
        $('.highlightPanel').removeClass('highlightPanel');
        var target = $('#' + $(this).data('panelid'));
        $(target).addClass('highlightPanel');           
        var delay = setTimeout(function(){
            $(".highlightPanel").removeClass("highlightPanel");         
        }, 3000)
    })              
})
```